# OpenLayers: why class and ID selectors in <div> to contain a map

Tags: css, openlayers, openlayers-3

The very useful 'quickstart' includes both id and class css selectors in the html.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html

To attach the map object to the div, the map object takes a target into arguments. The value is the id of the div:

In other OL guidance e.g. the workshop code, then only id selector is used.

I understand the differences in selectivity, and I am aware of guidance to be less selective and use class over id e.g.  https://github.com/airbnb/css.

What I do not understand is why class and id selectors maybe needed together for a fairly simple map-based app.

I have searched through OL GH pages, SO, GIS-SE etc and see no clear guidance on this key aspect of displaying a map object.

Comment: Thanks to JGH for a quick reply- that I will accept. As I said in my question  I already know the general different use cases of id and class css selectors. I am puzzled by the down votes, as the OL guidance is not clear (conflicting as pointed out in my question), on this very basic point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, you need the `id` because the map output will be displayed in a single `div`. Should you have two maps on a page, you would need two `div` with different `id`, so that the two maps can display different content.
Example: a zoomed-in map for a given address and a neighborhood map.

Now if you just have one map, you could style it using its `id`, i.e. you set the size, borders etc to the div `id`. But if you have several maps on your site, you will want some common styling, which relies on using a `class`.